# Node.js Express sendFile() parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send some file using express function res.sendFile().
When I try to run it with predefined filename, it works normally. But when I try to appoint a variable from another function as a parameter, it just sends the empty file. I've already tried to compare these two strings, and they are matching. I just cannot understand.

Here is my working code:

```
let options = {
root: `${os.tmpdir}/somefolder` 


}
    let fileName = "something.pdf";
  res.sendFile(fileName, options , function(err){next()});
```

and here is what doesnt work for me:

```
let options = {
root: `${os.tmpdir}/somefolder` 


 }
  let fileName = returnFileName(arguments);
  res.sendFile(fileName, options , function(err){next()});
```

this function is just generating the file and sending back its name. As I said, I've already tried to compare these two variables, and the result was true. The functions end looks like this:

```
return `${data._id}.pdf`;
```

Thank you for any response.

Comment: Can you provide your returnFileName() function

Comment: Maybe a good idea to verify if the file is getting generated at the path specified and that folder is set as a static resource to be served by the express.

Comment: The function itself is pretty long. In a nutshell, it just creates file and sends its name. I just realized, that the file creation can be the reason. I think, that the sendFile function is called too early after the file is created. Is there any way, I can make there some delay or tell the sendFile function to wait for the file to be created? Thank you

Comment: @user269867 The folder is not set as a static resource, however, it worked for me in the example I posted above. Thank you.

Comment: you can add if fileName is the empty condition to make sure you have a valid filename . to add wait you can use setTimeout() or you can add await/async to your returnFileName (depending on your code)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me :)